# Split txt file having different <tags> with python with search

Tags: python, xml, txt

I have a [text file] which I want to split and convert into various XML files using Python. I want to search the specific tag `<seq` and split the file from there. Also, in order to convert the file into structured XML, I have to store the values of the text inside those tags.

Note that `<seq` is not a closed tag in the text file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nv-G4Zp9Lmf3nqz9-9lCt-nUiO7CghQ8/view?usp=sharing

Here is what I tried so far:

```py
with open("1.txt" , "r") as file:
with open ("2.txt", "w") as out:
 page = file.read()
 seq_exit = True

 while seq_exit:
     pos = page.find("<seq")
     if pos == -1:
         seq_exit = False
     else:
         pos1 = page.find("<seq")
         pos2 = page.find("<seq", pos1+1)
         matter = page[pos1:pos2]
         out.write(matter)
         page = page[pos2:]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far. Explain what you need help with exactly. Paste the contents of the text file into the question.

Comment: I have mentioned what i have tried but unable to paste the txt matter in the box so provided google drive link

Comment: Access denied. You need to allow everyone access to the Google Drive link.

Comment: maybe you should run modules for xml files - like `xml`, `lxml`, `beausifulsoup`